# Date Parameter is an Illegal Arguments in Aura Method

Tags: date, aura

I have this method

```
    public static string method (Date startDate, Date endDate){
         if(startDate > endDate)
         {
             system.debug(' startDate: '+startDate+' endDate: '+endDate+' today date: '+System.today());
         }

   }
```

It throws an exception

> FATAL_ERROR|System.UnexpectedException: Illegal arguments

The debugging result is

```
startDate: 2016-2-20 endDate: 2016-2-29 today date: 2016-02-11 00:00:00
```

**Edit:**

Start Date field in the component:

```
<ui:inputDate aura:id="startDate" label="{!$Label.c.Start_Date}" value="{!v.startDate}" displayDatePicker="true"/>
```

- Controller is called normally which calls  the method in helper
- Helper:

> ```
>  var action = component.get("c.method");
>             action.setParams({ 
>                 startDate: component.get("v.startDate"),
>                 endDate: component.get("v.endDate"),
>             });
> ```

So Any idea why this exception is thrown?

Comment: Can you share how your component is calling them ?

Comment: I edited the answer to include what you asked for. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I just tried debugging this and seems like no issues at all.

Here is the code that worked all good with below code

```
<aura:component controller="ApexCls">
<aura:attribute name="startDate" type="Date"/>
<ui:inputDate aura:id="startDate" label="tEST" value="{!v.startDate}" displayDatePicker="true"/>
<ui:button press="{!c.checkdate}" label="Find"/>
```

JS controller

```
({
checkdate : function(component, event, helper) {
    var action = component.get("c.getmethod");
        var self = this;
        action.setParams({
            startDate: component.get("v.startDate")
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        console.log('STATE'+response.getReturnValue());
            if (component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS") {
            }else if (state === "ERROR") {
                var errors = response.getError();
                if (errors) {
                    $A.logf("Errors", errors);
                    if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                        $A.error("Error message: " +
                                 errors[0].message);
                    }
                } else {
                    $A.error("Unknown error");
                }
            }
        });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
   }
 })
```

The apex class

```
public class ApexCls {

  @AuraEnabled
  public static void  getmethod (Date startDate){
     system.debug('startDate:'+startDate);
  }

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I got it working by changing the method signature to receive date as a string then convert it as follows:

```
public static string method (string dateStart, string dateEnd){
    date startDate = Date.valueOf(dateStart);
}
```

By the way, the date parameter was being passed correctly but yet we got problems. Receiving it as a string then convert it fixed the problem.

Comment: check below ..I got it working as below

Comment: Are you using design attribute ?

Comment: No, I'm not using design attribute.

Comment: I dont think then you need to use string for your conversion .Date works good to me .If you could please post what went wrong and how you solved it ,it will be great help

Comment: It is weird but really it did not work till I changed the date passed to string then converted it into Date in Apex method. Have no idea why.